# What is strictness?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In Haskell, I try to understand the notion of strictness. I understand that

```
const x y = x
```

is strict on the first argument but not on the second.
But is

```
 ifFun pred cons alt = if pred then cons else alt
```

strict? It is strict on the first argument. I understand that the fact that cons and alt are evaluated depending on the value of pred. Does that mean the function is not strict on those arguments?

Comment: How much do you understand about lazy evaluation? You need to understand this before you can understand strictness.

Comment: When there is only one argument, I think you understand it pretty well. With multiple arguments, it's more subtle. Sometimes, as in `const x y` one argument is evaluated, another is not, so it's clear. Sometimes, as in your other example, we have "conditional strictness" in the sense that some argument may be evaluated or not, depending on the others. I'm unsure about a completely standard, widespread term for such cases. (IIRC GHC's internal strictness analyzer calls "absent" those args which are surely never evaluated, "strict" those who surely always are, and "lazy" the rest)

Comment: By the way, I think your doubt is about the multi-argument case, not the single argument one (which I believe you understood). If so, I'd suggest to make the title more precise.

Answer (score 7):

"Strict" is one of those words that has a precise technical meaning that has been coopted by the community to mean something a bit less formal. Here's the technical definition.

#### Function `f` is *strict* if `f ⊥ = ⊥`.

Here ⊥ is the standard symbol for an undefined computation; generally in denotational semantics there is just one and all undefined computations are indistinguishable from each other, but in Haskell as a concession to practicality we have many different kinds that can be distinguished: exceptions, infinite loops, pattern match failures, and so on. For the purposes of this answer, we'll consider them all equal.

Let's ask if `const` is strict. We have

```
const = \x -> \y -> x
```

hence

```
const ⊥ = \y -> ⊥ ≠ ⊥
```

and therefore `const` is not strict. But, oh, we've lost some very important communication power here! There is a good sense in which, when applied to undefined behavior, `const` doesn't behave well. So many people will say "strict in the *n*th argument" and we'll pretty much understand what they mean. It isn't obvious how to define what they mean formally, but a half-decent first stab at it goes something like this:

#### If function `f` has *m* arguments, then it is *strict in the nth argument* for some *n* ≤ *m* when ∀ a1, ..., am. f a1 a2 ... a(n-1) ⊥ a(n+1) ... am = ⊥.

(Aside: why isn't this quite right? For many functions -- including `const` -- we can't statically know how many arguments it has. Although `const` looks like it might be a two-argument function, `const id () ()` is perfectly well typed and applies `const` to three arguments.)

Now we can say something like "`const` is strict on its first argument" and have it mean what we want it to mean (provided, as above, that `const` actually is a two-argument function), because ∀`y`. `const ⊥ y = ⊥` does indeed hold.

We now also have the tools to address your question about `ifFun`, namely: is `ifFun` strict on its second argument? That is, can we cook up `pred` and `alt` such that

```
ifFun pred ⊥ alt ≠ ⊥ -- ?
```

I think it's clear we can do so, since:

```
ifFun False ⊥ () = if False then ⊥ else () = () ≠ ⊥
```

A similar argument shows that `ifFun` is "not strict on its third argument" in the popular understanding of this phrase (again modulo the provisos discussed above), but *is* "strict on its first argument".

Comment: Yikes, after a bit of thought, I can't work out a really good convention for when to `monospace` things in this answer, so the formatting here is a bit inconsistent. Please let me know if the formatting has caused confusion and I'll try again.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a stretch to claim that `const` is applied to three arguments, even when treating curried functions as if they were multi-argument functions.